# Count number of lines in file using batch

Tags: command-line, batch, notepad++, batch-file

I am using TrailerCount.bat file to count the number of lines in text file using below mentioned code

```
@Echo off
::set newline=^& echo.

SET FilePath=%1

Set /a _Lines=0

For /f %%j in ('Type %FilePath%^|Find "" /v /c ') Do Set /a _Lines=%%j

(
echo TRAILER %_Lines% 
)>>%FilePath%
```

Here when I am passing the txt file as a first input to batch file. After running it, its giving me Trailer as 8 in the last line of Text File which is correct if we open text file with "NOTEPAD". But using "Notepad++" it should be 11.

What changes i need to make to  count empty lines,etc to get correct trailer count with respect to Notepad++???

Answer (score 3):

The batch file is working correctly. `find` won't count a line *unless* it has the Windows `LFCR*` symbols on the line. You need to change the text file to have the `LFCR` symbols at the end of each line.

*`LFCR` is `Line Feed, Carriage Return`.

Comment: @abhayk, if the file doesn't have the line feed (LF) and carriage return (CR) characters used by Microsoft Windows, because it was produced on a computer using another operating system, such as Linux, OS X, etc., you can convert from the [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) representation on another OS using techniques mentioned at [Windows command to convert unix eol to windows eol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579553/windows-command-to-convert-unix-eol-to-windows-eol)