# How to find count of lines present in a file using batch script

Tags: command-line, batch

I want to count the number of lines in a file using batch.

I have gone through [this](https://superuser.com/questions/948237/count-number-of-lines-in-file-using-batch), but couldn't understand as I am a beginner. I have written my own piece of code with basic knowledge.

```
@echo off
set "file=abc.csv"
set /a x=0
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in ("%file%") do (
  echo %x%
  pause>nul
  set /a x=%x%+1
)
```

When I run the above code I am getting **0** as output. Can someone please help me in sorting out the error?

Comment: I know you said "Batch" but it always hurts me to see way too difficult and unreadeable code for such an easy task. So here's a PowerShell Solution: `$a = (get-content "C:\abc.csv" | measure-object).count` the $a variable now contains the number of lines in your file.

Comment: @SimonS Command line is also a one liner ;) See my answer. I find batch files easier to read than PowerShell ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill but you're (don't get  me wrong here) an old-school master of disaster ;-). if you're new to windows scripting, powershell is definetly easier to read. no /v or /c switch where you need to read a help file to get it's meaning. additionally PowerShell is the new cmd (it's successor) and I would encourage any admin/scripter to use PowerShell instead of cmd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I want to count the number of lines in a file using batch

**Specific solution**

From a command line:

```
F:\test>for /f "usebackq" %b in (`type abc.csv ^| find "" /v /c`) do @echo line count is %b
line count is 1
```

From a batch file (countlines.cmd):

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  for /f "usebackq" %%b in (`type abc.csv ^| find "" /v /c`) do (
    echo line count is %%b
    )
  )
```

Example:

```
F:\test>countlines
line count is 1
F:\test>
```

**Flexible solution**

Use the following batch file (countlines.cmd):

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`dir /b /s %1`)  do (
  echo processing file %%a
  for /f "usebackq" %%b in (`type %%a ^| find "" /v /c`) do (
    echo line count is %%b
    set /a lines += %%b
    )
  )
echo total lines is %lines%
```

Notes:

- Total number of lines is stored in `%lines%`.
- Batch file supports wildcards.
- Tweak `echo ...` commands as appropriate.

Usage:

```
countlines filename_expression
```

Example:

```
F:\test>countlines *.csv
processing file F:\test\abc.csv
line count is 1
processing file F:\test\def.csv
line count is 1
total lines is 2
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [find](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) - Search for a text string in a file & display all the lines where it is found.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to count the number of lines in a file on a Microsoft Windows system is by using the following command:

`find /v /c "" somefile.txt`

The `/c` option counts the number of lines while the `/v` option displays all lines NOT containing the specified string.  Since the null string, i.e. "", is treated as never matching, you should see the number of lines in the file displayed - see the [Stupid command-line trick: Counting the number of lines in stdin](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110825-00/?p=9803) article at Raymond Chen's Microsoft Developer Blog, [The Old New Thing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/) for an explanation of why this works and how a bug in the earliest [MS-DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS) version of the find command became a feature that remains to this day. The MS-DOS operating system was an operating system for early PCs provided by Microsoft long before the company created Microsoft Windows.

Comment: This is also working perfect @moonpoint . Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting count of zero because delayed expansion is turned off.
You've already `set /a x=0`

The value of `x` inside the `for` loop doesn't change with `%x%`. Replace it with `!x!`

Try this:

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@echo off
set "file=abc.csv"
set /a x=0
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in ("%file%") do (
  echo !x!
  pause>nul
  set /a x=!x!+1
)
```

A simpler way to count the number of lines in a file using batch:

`find /v "" /c < abc.csv`

Comment: +1 for the inspiration to simplify this with a temporary file.