# Windows ftp command: How to count number of files in remote directory?

Tags: ftp, batch-file

When I use the Windows `ftp` command at the command window which I think is the DOS [`ftp` command](http://www.michael-thomas.com/tech/ftpinfo/dosftpnotes.htm), is there a way to count the number of files in the remote directory? That way I can check that I ftp'ed them all. I am stuck using Window 7 built-in commands and can't use a different program.

Comment: W7 has Powershell installed. I would suggest using that.

Comment: PowerShell was new to me, and if anyone else wants background: What is PowerShell, http://www.digitalcitizen.life/simple-questions-what-powershell-what-can-you-do-it , example of using it to count ftp files, http://salvoz.com/blog/2013/07/21/powershell-ftp-scripts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Save remote file list to a file;
- [Count number of lines in the file](https://superuser.com/q/948237/213663).

```
@echo off

echo open ftp.example.com>ftp.txt
echo user>>ftp.txt
echo password>>ftp.txt
echo ls /remote/path files.txt>>ftp.txt
echo bye>>ftp.txt

ftp -s:ftp.txt

set /a LINES=0
for /f %%j in ('type files.txt^|find "" /v /c ') do set /a LINES=%%j

del files.txt
del ftp.txt

echo Number of files: %LINES%
```

---

As others have commented, using PowerShell script would be more elegant and reliable though.

Comment: the question says "count the files in a directory", not "count the lines in a file"

Comment: @ashleedawg Sure. And the answer shows how to do that by saving the file list to a file and counting the lines in the file. It wouldn't be the *accepted* answer, if it did not answer the question. If you have a better way how to count the files in a batch file, please post your own answer.